# Simple host monitoring solution

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I am looking for a host monitoring solution for an infrastructure I have to manage.

Since this infrastructure is on-premise, I would like to have a client-server architecture, where a client reports status to an external server (EC2 instance) periodically.

I tried Zabbix for this purpose, but it did not work very well. The connection dropped whenever the agent tried to connect to the server, likely due to firewall rules. Also, I would like to have some level of auto-discovery instead of having to manually entering hosts (this is a "want", not necessarily a "must"). I would try to add a Zabbix Proxy, but then I would have to add the proxy in another on-premise host, which would have to be monitored itself (hence the server on an EC2 instance)

Answer (score 1):

Zabbix is still one of your best options, you just have to invest more time into configuring it.
It offers [autodiscovery](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/discovery/network_discovery/rule) with templates to configure the monitored services and alerts.

It is also self-hosted, free and open-source.

We monitor with it hundreds of machines and it has never failed us.

About the dropped agent -> server connection, you should check first if your server firewall allows port 10000 inbound for the agent connection, then on the agent configuration if the [Server/ServerActive directive](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/appendix/config/zabbix_agentd) lists the server IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I have also only had bad experiences with Zabbix, PRTG is in my opinion better in every way.

Anyway, here are some suggestions:

- Host the monitoring server on-prem aswell.
- Set up a site-to-site VPN between AWS and your on-prem network.
- Use a hosted monitoring sollution, like [Datadog](https://www.datadoghq.com/). It works pretty much exactly as you want with the client reporting to the service.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of monitoring solutions available. One option is Prometheus which utilizes agents on the boxes and scrapes little mini-webservers for status which can then be visualized with something like grafana.

Another option which is similar is Elasticsearch and the *beat (filebeat, metricbeat, etc) plugins that it utilizes but rather than scraping, they push to the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Azure has a set of services which provide server monitoring and management for Windows/Linux OS.
It works simply by installing an agent on the server which connects to the could. No separate monitoring server necessary for this. And it supports monitoring any servers: on-premises, AWS or any other cloud.
Check https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/azure-management

I believe AWS has a similar solution called CloudWatch, but never tried it personally, so I could not recommend.